# Best way to integrate and cross promote on search results page

Tags: search-results

I want to get everyone's feedback on which of the following mock-ups is the more user friendly way to cross-promote two different products on the search results page.  If you have a better way, please feel free to share as well.  *Please don't forget to provide reasons why as part of your answer.*

I'm designing a search results page for a site that sells kitchen related products (like cookware, bakeware, kitchen appliances, etc.) and an content section for recipes.  I would like to cross promote these two main "things" on the search results page and I have came up with the following:

**1) Related Recipes or Products banner at the top of the search results to let users know "by the way, we have these related items as well."**

[image]

**2) Related Recipes or Products banner integrated into the results so user see the related products/recipes as they browse.**

[image]

**3) Related Recipes or Products panel to the right of the results.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of those three are any good.
The main problems are
1) you lose screen real-estate when you have a sprawling section of recipes. 
2) "related recipes" - makes it sound like you're searching for recipes, not kitchenware.
3) you get screen clutter when you start mixing up different products

Remember, people hate ads. So, if you have to include them, make them look nice.
I would suggest you have them at the bottom showing one recipe at a time but making an effort to make that recipe look good. Carousel through them so they look less like ads. Keep it out of the way, people are there for kitchenware. They can't even cook whatever is on those recipes without the kitchenware!

Comment: I agree. People tend to have banner-blindness unless it looks like part of the content.